# How to make my program recognize if the string is containing numbers and save them to another string ? C++

Tags: c++, string

I made my program to recognize the numbers,but now I want to save the numbers from string a to  string c. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    char a[15] = "235634sdfg123";
    char b[11] = "0123456789";
    char c[15];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++)
        {
            if (a[i] == b[y])
            {
                cout << a[i] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you be more clear on what you are trying to do? I don't get what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Which string to be copied where? Please specify.

Comment: Apart from the lack of requirement clarity, it's common to compare chars against just '0' and '9' when looking for codes representing decimal characters.  If it's less than '0', or greater than '9', then it's not a decimal character code.  You don't need a loop.

Comment: It's still unclear. Does "235634sdfg123" contain one or two 'numbers'?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  auto a = "235634sdfg123"s;
  auto x = std::string{};

  std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(x),
               [](auto c) { return std::isdigit(c); });

  cout << x << endl; // 235634123
}
```

This uses `c++14` but can be easily adapted to old `C++` if needed.

This uses `std::string` instead of `char[]` because... well... because `C++`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the following?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    char a[15] = "235634sdfg123";
    char c[15];

    *std::copy_if( a, a + std::strlen( a ), c,
                   []( char c )
                   {
                    return std::isdigit( ( unsigned char )c );
                   } ) = '\0';

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
235634sdfg123
235634123
```

Or you could do the same using an ordinary loop. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    char a[15] = "235634sdfg123";
    char c[15];

    char *p = a;
    char *q = c;

    do
    {
        if ( std::isdigit( ( unsigned char ) *p ) || *p == '\0' ) *q++ = *p;
    } while ( *p++ );

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same as above

```
235634sdfg123
235634123
```

Comment: @Mario Tanev  See my uodated post that shows how to do the same using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, the simpliest solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define ssize 15

int main()
{
    char a[ssize] = "23d1d567d8d9";
    char c[ssize];
    memset(c, 0, ssize);

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ssize; i++)
    {
        if ('0' <= a[i] && a[i] <= '9')
        {
            c[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    cout << a << endl;
    cout << c << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

incrementing a counter k and using it to set data in char array c as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    char a[] = "235634sdfg123";
    char b[] = "0123456789";
    char c[15];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeof(b); y++)
        {
            if (a[i] == b[y])
            {
                c[k] = a[i];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```